# How to exclude request with {format} drf-yasg?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-yasg

everyone. I'm writing docs for my api on drf with using drf-yasing. And each of my requests has a copy with {format}. How i can delete that? [that my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmbn1.png)

For example my easy view:

```
@swagger_auto_schema(method='GET', manual_parameters=[params_id])
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_service_history(request):

    service = Service.objects.get(id=request.GET['id'])
    ser = ServiceHistorySerializer(service.service_history.all(), many=True)
    return Response(ser.data)
```

Url:

```
path('deleted_service/', views.deleted_service)
```

ps sorry for my english :)

Comment: are you using ***`format_suffix_patterns(...)`*** function?

Comment: yes, i am using it

Answer (score 2):

Thank JPG for help. I solved my problem just deleting than line in my urls

```
urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns
```